# Save() sets the headers automatically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am calling mongoose's save() function to save a record, and awaiting for it inside a express router, but for some reason, after the save() call, headers are automatically set. I have no idea how it happens automatically.

So any res.send() after this throws an error.

```
  app.get("/", async (req,res) => {

     // Some code 

     // Headers are not set yet.
    await newrecord.save(); // Saved But at this point headers are set automatically.

    res.send("hello"); // Throws error saying headers are set. Can you help?

    })
```

Comment: `save()` has no access to `res`, so it must be something else. Express middleware maybe?

Comment: I am in fact calling a module function in place of save(), but that module function inside calls mongoose save(). I use middlewares but none of them update the 'res'. And you know, just before calling this modulefunction to save the record headers are NOT set, but just after it is set.  Things are fine, when I don't use await. But I really need to await.